# How to expand the expansion panel in mat-table by a button click?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular9, angular-material-table

I was following this [Mat Expansion table](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vjjyayoqjno?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) to create a expansion panel for each row. I've disabled the row click to expand the panel by `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` in `mat-cell`. Now I need to expand the panel on a button edit. Below is my code for the same:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="ELEMENT_DATA.length>0">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="No">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.no}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Category">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="">
        <mat-slide-toggle>Inactive</mat-slide-toggle>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" style="margin-right: 5px;">EDIT</button>
        <button mat-flat-button color="warn">DELETE</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <div class="example-element-description">
            <form>
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width create-fields">
                <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
                <input matInput name="category" ngModel>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-slide-toggle>Inactive</mat-slide-toggle>
              <button mat-flat-button color="primary" style="display: inline;margin-left: 50px;">Update</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="example-element-row" [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    ></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
<h1 *ngIf="ELEMENT_DATA.length == 0" class="message">No Categories Added Yet</h1>
```

I want the `EDIT` button to work as the expander.
What necessary changes do I need to make ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add to DisplayColumns a new column 'action'

```
columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position','action'];
```

Then change the code where you defined the columns

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column!='action'?column:''}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      {{element[column]}} 
      <button *ngIf="column=='action'" 
       (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
             click</button>
      </td>
</ng-container>
```

See that the code in the button (click) is the same that you had in the (click) in the `<tr mat-row *matRowDef..>` (don't forget remove from this last)

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3ebgk?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.html)

Comment: I don't know  why my ```element[column]``` value is not getting fetched though am not getting any console error rest is still working perfectly. Thanks for that

Comment: element is the whole object. you can check it if you write `{{element|json}}` -well your table crash, but you can see the object-. `column` get the value of the elements in columnsToDisplay (that is an array of strings). is element has a property equal to column, must be show it. check if you has a typo error and remember that Angular is case-sensitive

Comment: Don't copy from angular material website. Make your own example so that we can understand easily if we don't have the description for our own api.